# custom paging using ROW_NUMBER() in sql for asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview

I am trying to implement a custom paging for gridview in asp.net using ROW_NUMBER() in sql.  The (classic) query below works great, however its performance is not that great since I have to copy the whole table to a new table and then select 20 records from the new table.  It sometimes even works better without paging, just retrieving all records at once.  I tried to use ROW_NUMBER() in where clause but sql does not allow me to do that.  How can I improve the query below? What would be your suggestions? I guess I need to find a way to eliminate the process of copying the whole dataset to a new table, but how?

```
SELECT PostId, Message, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastUpdateDateTime DESC)) as Row   

INTO #Results   
FROM   Posts
WHERE  Posts.TimePointId=@TimePointId AND IsFixed=0 

ORDER BY LastUpdateDateTime DESC

-----------------------------------------------------


SELECT * FROM #Results
WHERE Row BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

DROP TABLE #Results
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really dont need to use a temp table for such simple operation just use a sub query or CTE.

**Using Sub Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT PostId, Message, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastUpdateDateTime DESC)) as Row    
FROM   Posts
WHERE  Posts.TimePointId=@TimePointId AND IsFixed=0 
) Sub
WHERE Row BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 
AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
```

**Using CTE**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
 (
    SELECT PostId, Message, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastUpdateDateTime DESC)) as Row     
    FROM   Posts
    WHERE  Posts.TimePointId=@TimePointId AND IsFixed=0 
 )
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE Row BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 
AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
```

Comment: I tried this already but it does not recognize Row: Invalid column name 'Row'.

Comment: @erkaner Did you use a Sub query ??? you need to use a subquery the row number is not visiable to the query in which its being generated. you need to use a sub-query or a CTE to manipulate results based on row numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will fix your performance problem, you can can use a subquery instead of a temporary table:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT PostId, Message, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastUpdateDateTime DESC)) as Row    
      FROM   Posts
      WHERE  Posts.TimePointId=@TimePointId AND IsFixed=0 
     ) p
WHERE Row BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `CTE`;

```
;With CTE as
(
SELECT PostId, Message, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastUpdateDateTime DESC)) as Row   
FROM   Posts
WHERE  Posts.TimePointId=@TimePointId AND IsFixed=0 

ORDER BY LastUpdateDateTime DESC

)SELECT Row,* FROM CTE
WHERE Row BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
```